# Property of periodic continuous mapping

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\ne0\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous mapping with period $p>0$. Is it true that $id\cdot f$ is not uniformly continuous?

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ where $f(a)\ne0$ and $\delta>0$. If $1\leq p<\delta$, then $|a+p-a|<\delta$ and $|(a+p)f(a+p)-af(a)|=|pf(a)|\geq|f(a)|$. What to do $\delta\leq p$ or $p<1$? Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is not constant.  For any $\delta >0,$ fix $x,y$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ and $f(x)\ne f(y)$... (Note $x,y$ exist because $f$ is continuous but not constant)...

Now for any $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $|(x+np)-(y+np)|<\delta.$ But $$|(x+np)f(x+np)-(y+np)f(y+np)|=$$ $$=|np(f(x)-f(y))+(xf(x)-yf(y)|\ge$$ $$\ge np|f(x)-f(y)|-|xf(x)-yf(y)|,$$ which has no upper bound over the set of all $n\in\Bbb N.$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a couple questions if you don't mind..(1) Given $\delta>0$ how can you use continuity and nonconstant to find $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $f(x)\ne f(y)$? The fact that $f$ is non constant gives that there exist $x,y$ such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$, but how do you ensure that $|x-y|<\delta$? (2) I am not sure how $|(x+np)f(x+np)-(y+np)f(y+np)|\geq np|f(x)-f(y)|-|xf(x)-yf(y)|$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can be used to find an $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon\leq|(x+np)f(x+np)-(y+np)f(y+np)|$; can you pls elaborate on this?

Comment: Suppose $f$ is continuous and $x_1<x_2$ and $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2).$  Let $x=\sup \{z\in [x_1,x_2): f(z)=f(x_1)\}.$ Then $f(x)=f(x_1)$ so $x<x_2.$ Now if $\delta >0$ let $x<y<x+\min (x_1-x,\delta)<x_2.$ By def'n of $x$ we have $f(y)\ne f(x_1)=f(x)$ and we have $|x-y|<\delta.$

Comment: An alternative method:  Suppose there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. Then for  $x\ne 0 $ let $n\in\Bbb N$ where  $(n-1)\delta /2\le |x| <n\delta /2 .$ Consider the finite sequence $(x_0,..., x_n)$ where $x_n=x$ and $x_j=jx/n $ when $0\le j<n$.  We have $f(x)=f(x_n)=f(x_{n-1})=...=f(x_0)=f(0)$ because $|x_{j+1}-x_j|<\delta$ for $0\le j<n$... So $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x. $ (& we don't need continuity of $f$).

Comment: For your 2nd query, take $n\in \Bbb N$ large enough that $np|f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon +|xf(x)-yf(y)|.$